# IONIC 4 ion-content inner-scroll scrollbar color/theme w/ Electron app

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, electron, ionic4

The following is my attempt to theme the scrollbars:

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px !important;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #333 !important;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #111 !important;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #111 !important;
}
```

However, this has not made any impact and I'm still getting the same default windows/chrome scrollbars.

Can someone please advise.

Answer (score 8):

1. create a scrollbar directive

   ```
   import { NgModule, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
   @Directive({
     selector: '[appScrollbarTheme]'
   })
   export class ScrollbarThemeDirective {
     constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       const stylesheet = `
         ::-webkit-scrollbar {
         width: 10px;
         }
         ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
         background: #0f0f0f;
         }
         ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
         border-radius: 1rem;
         background: linear-gradient(var(--ion-color-light-tint), var(--ion-color-light));
         border: 4px solid #020202;
         }
         ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
         }
       `;

       const styleElmt = el.nativeElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('style');

       if (styleElmt) {
         styleElmt.append(stylesheet);
       } else {
         const barStyle = document.createElement('style');
         barStyle.append(stylesheet);
         el.nativeElement.shadowRoot.appendChild(barStyle);
       }

     }
   }


   @NgModule({
     declarations: [ ScrollbarThemeDirective ],
     exports: [ ScrollbarThemeDirective ]
   })
   export class ScrollbarThemeModule {}
   ```
2. add this to app.module

   `import { ScrollbarThemeModule } from './scrollbar-theme.directive';
   @NgModule({
     imports: [ScrollbarThemeModule]
   })`
3. in your html

   `<ion-content  appScrollbarTheme>`

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue for this in the Ionic GitHub repository, as of now, it is unresolved (not known to be possible): https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17685